# postgresql query result to csv prints current page's html code also

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to output the results of a PostgreSQL query to CSV format using PHP.

On the main page is a link that sends the SQL statements as a string to another function in another PHP class, which in turn takes the SQL and executes the query using pg_query() and return the result sets.

My problem is that when I open the CSV file, all the results of my query are there, but at the end of the file I see the HTML code from the page that sent the query.

I looked at several StackOverflow posts, but to no avail.

Here is my code:

Main class:

```
$o .= '<p>You can convert the result set to CSV format to be opened in Excel.</p>';

$link = array('op1' => 'PatternExport', 'op2' => 'outputToCSV', 'id' => $pattern_id, 'data' => $pattern_SQL);

$o .= '<a href="' . $this->oQS->buildEncryptedURL($link) . '">Download Query Results as CSV File</a>';
```

Receiving class:

```
function outputToCSV()
{ 
    $ptid = $this->oQS->getValue('id');
    $sql = $this->oQS->getValue('data');

    $href = $this->oQS->buildEncryptedURL(array('op1'=>'PatternManager', 'op2'=>'listPatterns'),'/aatsc/index.php');
    $result = pg_query($sql);

    // filename for download 
    $filename = "query_results_" . date('Ymd') . "_" . $ptid . ".csv"; 

    $output = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:' . (12*1024*1024), 'rw+');
    foreach(pg_fetch_assoc($result,0) AS $field=>$value)
    {
        $output .= '' . $field . ',';
    }
    $output = rtrim($output,',') . "\n";


    for($i=0;$i<pg_num_rows($result);$i++)
    {
        foreach(pg_fetch_assoc($result,$i) AS $field=>$value) 
            $output .= '' . $value . ',';
        $output = rtrim($output,',') . "\n";
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\";");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    print($output);
    //$href = $this->oQS->buildEncryptedURL(array('op1'=>'PatternManager', 'op2'=>'listPatterns'),'/aatsc/index.php');
    //header("Location: $href");  
}
```

Could you tell me whether I am using the right approach to export query results to CSV, and what in my code is causing the whole HTML code to be streamed?

Thanks

Comment: And what happens after the `outputToCSV()` function call? If there's html code after that, it will end up in the file. In this case, insert `exit(0);` after the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're generating $output twice, if you remove the foreach loop & fopen line, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You merely just need to issue the [SQL COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) statement as follows:

```
COPY (select * from tbl) to stdout with csv header
```

resulting in:

```
col1,col2,col3
2013-05-22 07:28:59.732,192.168.1.67,3
```

Comment: That would work with the `psql` program but **not with php**. There is [pg_copy_to](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-to.php) in php but it doesn't do CSV so not really useful in the context of this question